# Plagiarism, copy of code

Tags: licensing

In the academic world, plagiarism and referencing are taken seriously. And when it comes to our intellectual creation, to what extent it would be plagiarism copy and paste snippets of other code, available on the Internet at mine?

Particularly I never referenciei the code snippets that I copied in SO. This is plagiarism? The legal punishment is the same for plagiarism in the academic world?

Answer (score 1):

In the commercial world, the main issue is Copyright and Copyright law.  Basically, it is illegal to copy something unless you have the permission of the copyright owner.  The legal punishment for copyright violation can be large civil damages, large fines and even jail time, depending on the legal jurisdiction and the nature and severity of the violations.

Other qualitative differences between plagiarism and copyright violation include:

- Plagiarism is punished by Universities kicking out students, and sacking staff ... and "public shaming".  Copyright violation is punished by the law courts with civil damages, or criminal fines and jail terms.
- Universities are actively looking for instances of plagiarism, certainly at the undergraduate level<sup>1</sup> ... where it is commonplace.  Copyright violation is generally up to the copyright holder to detect.
- For plagiarism, the Universities, etc take the initiative for prosecution.  For copyright violation, it is generally up to the copyright owner to pursue the violators via the civil court system.

---

A programmer who copies snippets of code is *unlikely* to fall foul of copyright law.  Copyright law allows for "fair use" and there are also *de minimus* arguments.  However, a lawyer can still *threaten* to take you to court ... and it would cost you money to fight them.

A programmer or company that wholesale copies entire applications (e.g. open source) in violation of the copyright / license is taking a significant risk.

---

> Particularly I never reference the code snippets that I copied in SO. This is plagiarism?

Yes.  Plagiarism is copying without attribution and claiming the work as your own.

Does it matter?

Only if the context in which you are copying the code snippets *requires* attribution (referencing).  (Open source software licenses generally don't ... but Creative Commons licenses often do!)

But the copying *does* matter if it is a copyright violation!

Read the StackOverflow [legal](https://stackexchange.com/legal) page *carefully* to understand if what you are doing is permitted.

---

<sup>1 - AFAIK, there are no systematic attempts to detect plagiarism in RHD theses or published research papers.  On the other hand, the consequences for the plagiariser are much, much worse; e.g. it can mean the end of a career.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

See the bottom of this page and all pages on SO: when you copy a snippet of code from SO, these terms apply:

"user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required",

as explained here: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/

Reuse is not plagiarism, and to reuse you need to comply with the terms of the license and this require attribution per the CC-BY-SA-3.0 license http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/

If you do not comply with the license terms, you are simply not licensed (i.e. not authorized) to reuse this code. This is the extent of the "punishment"!

/IANAL /TINLA